# Why is bash -c behaving strangely

Tags: bash, curl, syntax, syntax-error

I have a file called `wait_script.sh` with the following contents

```
#!/bin/bash
until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://localhost:4001);do
  printf '.'
  sleep 5
done
```

I can run it with:

```
./wait_script.sh
```

and it works as expected

I am able to run the same thing with:

```
until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://localhost:4001);do;printf '.';sleep 5;done
```

But when I try to run it inside of `bash -c`, I get the following error:

```
bash -c "until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://localhost:4001);do;printf '.';sleep 5;done"

bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
bash: -c: line 0: `until ;do;printf '.';sleep 5;done'
```

Why is this error happening and how can I run the command inside of `bash -c`?

Comment: A semicolon cannot follow the `do` keyword; it effectively *is* a semicolon. See shellcheck.net.

Comment: You probably do not want to place the -c command in double quotes because that will run curl exactly once and *not* repeatedly. After fixing the syntax error, try using single quotes.

Comment: I still have the same error with `bash -c "until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://localhost:4001);do printf '.';sleep 5;done"`

Comment: I have falled victim to the [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), this is what I actually wanted to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264444/travis-run-curl-wait-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors:

1. `do` is a terminator itself for an arbitrary command list that could contain a `;`-delimited list of commands. It is not itself a command to be terminated by a `;`. Omit the semicolon between `do` and `printf`.
2. You don't want a command substitution here at all; `until` uses the exit status of `curl` to determine when to end the loop. Your original code only works because `curl` doesn't produce any output for the shell to treat as a command, so `until` "runs" the empty command, which always succeeds, terminating the loop immediately.

You should write

```
bash -c 'until curl ...; do printf "."; sleep 5; done'
```

ensuring that no single quotes are used inside the argument to `-c`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, and sorry for the badly asked question. This answer may be useful, but does not actually answer the question I wanted to ask (really sorry about that). I would like to instead have [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264444/travis-run-curl-wait-script) (which you marked as a duplicate) answered. As they are apparently duplicates, I would like to remove this question and instead keep the other one.

Comment: The above works (thank you), but is it possible to write anything which would do the same, but inside the double quotes `bash -c "..."`?

Comment: You can use double quotes, but you need to make sure anything that might be expanded inside double quotes is properly escaped.

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks for the hints. Everything works if I just escape the `$`

Comment: `bash -c "until \$(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://localhost:4001);do printf '.';sleep 5;done"` is a solution

Comment: No, you don't need the command substitution at all. Even if `curl` fails, the lack of output means `until` has an empty command to execute, which automatically "succeeds", making the loop terminate immediately. Get rid of the `$(...)` surrounding the call to `curl`.

Comment: The above line of bash only terminates when the curl command succeeds

Comment: I'm not sure I would count on that; there is *no need* for a command substitution when `curl` produces no output.

Comment: To clarify: when `curl` produces no output, `until` *seems* to go by the exit status of the command in the command substitution, but I can't find any documentation that it is *required* to. However, if it *is* going by the exit status, then you can get the exit status with `until curl ...; do` as well, with no need to capture the nonexistent output first.

Comment: Compare with `until $(echo foo); do ...; done`, which loops forever because the output `foo` isn't the name of a command that can be executed.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks @chepner, very thorough response